# Sequelize - convert this SQL query to Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

There is any way to convert this query to Sequelize?

```
SELECT
    A1.emp_id, A1.time AS check_in, A2.time AS check_out, 
    TIMEDIFF(A2.time, A1.time) AS total_time   
FROM 
    hours A1    
INNER JOIN 
    hours A2 ON (A1.emp_id = A2.emp_id 
             AND DATE(A1.time) = DATE(A2.time)) 
WHERE  
    A1.status = 'check_in' 
    AND A2.status = 'check_out' 
ORDER BY 
    A1.time DESC
```

Thank you,
Shail

Comment: Yes, there's a way. To be efficient, please post what you have gotten so far. This is possible duplicate question - see here for inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521665/select-from-multiple-tables-sequelize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already defined a Sequelize model for `hours` then you also need to define an association between `hours` and `hours`:

```js
Hours.belongsTo(models.Hours, { foreignKey: 'id', as: 'linkedHours' })
```

And then use `on` option in `include` to join `hours` with itself using your own conditions instead of linking them by `id`:

```js
const res = await Hours.findAll({
  attributes: ['emp_id', ['time', 'check_in'],
    [Sequelize.col('linkedHours.time'), 'check_out'],
    [Sequelize.fn('TIMEDIFF', Sequelize.col('linkedHours.time'), Sequelize.col('time')), 'total_time'],
  ],
  where: {
    status: 'check_in'
  },
  include: [{
    model: Hours,
    as: 'linkedHours',
    required: true,
    where: {
      status: 'check_out'
    },
    order: [['time', 'DESC']],
    on: {
          [Op.and]: [
            Sequelize.col('hours.emp_id'), '=', Sequelize.col('linkedHours.emp_id'),
            Sequelize.fn('DATE', Sequelize.col('hours.time')), '=', Sequelize.fn('DATE', Sequelize.col('linkedHours.time')),
          ]
       }
  }]
})
```